# how to get active group in Fabricjs

Tags: jquery, html, css, canvas, fabricjs

any way in fabrics to get active Group, i tried below code but it is not working ?

```
 $('.radius, .spacing, .align, .fontSize').change(function() {  
    var act = canvas.getActiveGroup();
        act.set($(this).attr('class'), $(this).val());  });

});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if (act != 'undefined') {
    act.set (attribute, $(this).val());
}
```

I don't think, group object have .radius attribute, or .spacing anyway, seems the first parameter of your set method is misled.

You can save data-attribute in your html element, and fetch it as well :

```
<a data-attribute='backgroundColor'>....</a>

var attribute = $(this).data('attribute');
act.set (attribute, $(this).val());
```

More better, I think.